# Can one of the fields in a Drupal webform be Wysiwyg HTML field?

Tags: drupal-8, drupal-webform

I want to have a field in a Drupal Webform where users can input some formatted HTML (tables, headers, etc.) Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.
The form element is called "Text format." This sounds like a format selector of some kind, but it's actually a text element. If you set it to "Basic HTML," for example, the CKEditor WYSYWIG loads.
The image below is an example (the 'field' labeled Notes/URL(s)). If users wish to enter HTML directly, the code view button in the toolbar allows for that.

[image]

Here's what the initial page of the webform config looks like for this element... [image]

Comment: I may be able to help. If the question doesn't mean what it seems to mean, perhaps you can clarify? But it seems clear. In Webform, fields are called elements. The element called "text format" set to Basic HTML or some other suitable text format results in "a field" where  "users can input some formatted HTML (tables, headers, etc.)."

Comment: I have edited to add an images.